# Page Not Found (404) using Django (first app)

Tags: python, django

I'm working on my first django app, and i'm a rookie at coding, sometimes i really dont get where is the error and the tutorials and documentation dont help me either.

The error is this one:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGeFe.jpg)

Now, the code i have for the views:

```
def update(request, id):
    cliente = get_object_or_404(Cliente, id=id)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = clienteForm(instance=cliente)
        return redirect("/clientepag/", id=id)

    else:
        form = clienteForm(request.POST, instance=cliente)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("/clientepag/", id=id)
        else:
            form = clienteForm()
            return redirect("/clientepag/", id=id)


def clientepag(request, id):
    cliente = Cliente.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request, 'clientepag.html', {'cliente': cliente})
```

I'm trying to make my update function to redirect me to clientepag/id, but i dont get why my clientepag function isnt getting the id i'm sending from the update, the db is being updated, i validated that, but the clientepag isnt getting the id i'm trying to send from the update, and i dont know if its the update that isnt sending the id, or the clientepag that isnt getting it, or is rejecting it.

I already validated that the update function still have the id after the form.save() line

My path list:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from clientesapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home),
    path('clnt/', views.clnt),
    path('view/', views.view),
    path('clientepag/<int:id>', views.clientepag),
    path('edit/<int:id>', views.edit),
    path('delete/<int:id>', views.delete),
    path('update/<int:id>', views.update)
]
```

I know the answer must be somthing trivial, but i really havent been able to grasp where that error could be.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your issue lies in the redirects:

```
return redirect("/clientepag/", id=id)
```

When you pass a URI (i.e. `"/clientepag/"`) to `redirect()` it won't be `reverse()` resolved by Django, which means that the kwargs that you passed to it (`id=id`) will be ignored.

The solution would be to pass a view name or the name of a path from your `urlpatterns` instead.

For example, to name your path in urls.py:

```
path('clientepag/<int:id>', views.clientepag, name='clientepag'),
```

And then your redirects become (if the `urlpatterns` are not namespaced):

```
return redirect('clientepag', id=id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with return redirect("/clientepag/", id=id) in code as here the id is ignored as you are using hardcoded url value instead of this you have below options.

Define a name parameter for clientepag url in urls.py file its a good practice and also helpful in avoid hardcoding of urls in code:

**Update the url as :**

```
path('clientepag/<int:id>', views.clientepag, name='clientepag'),
```

**Use name of url in redirect call:**

```
return redirect(reverse('clientepag', kwargs = {
                'id': form.instance.id
            }))
```

You can refer doc for more options for redirect :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#examples